# Wordpress User Rating another User plugin

Tags: plugins, wordpress, rating

I like to have a feature in my website such as If a user comments a video or his/her comment gets a upvote by a another user.  The posted user will gather points.  Also if the site Admin wishes they can give more points like +500 for a user.  I want things similar to ebay.

Do we have any plugin for this in Wordpress.  If there is no plugin available If I try to build this plugin Will that take more time.  I am new to wordpress.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need a commenting system which has options to do voting by another users. Take a look at [Disqus](http://www.disqus.com) or [Livefyre](http://www.livefyre.com). Both has functionality that you are looking for and very easy to integrate to a WordPress website.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply..I want something like ebay.com tod.com user will have rating as well as admin can grant points to them.